# (Android) Is it possible to change the shape of the polyline in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, colors, shapes, polyline

I know we can change the color of the polyline by using "polylineOptions.color(YOUR_COLOR);" bit is it possible to set a shape on it? (I would like the like to have a blue border and be white inside if the route that needs to be completed and if completed, set the color to blue -no more border)

This is what I have so far, I call this function 2 times, once for the completed path and then for the path to be completed:

```
  public void createProgressRouteOnMap( ArrayList<LatLng> route, boolean done){
    if(done) {
        if(polyline != null){
            polyline.remove();
        }
    }else{
        if(polyline2 != null){
            polyline2.remove();
        }
    }
    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyLineOptions.addAll(route);
    polyLineOptions.width(10);
    if(done){
        polyLineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
    }else{
        polyLineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_route));
    }
    if(mMap == null){
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    if(done) {
        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }else{
        polyline2 = mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }

}
```

Comment: go to this [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes?hl=it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes?hl=it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do?

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // Add a thick blue line
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng1, new LatLng2)
     .width(10)
     .color(Color.BLUE));
 // Add a thin white line
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng1, new LatLng2)
     .width(4)
     .color(Color.WHITE));
```

Comment: 10x, this did it for me